# Bootstrap dropdown menu set width based on innter elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap dropdown that has a bunch of `li`s inside. When one of them is selected, I programmatically add a checkmark on the right side.

Right now I have an `<li>` that looks something like:

```
<li data-original-index="1">
    <a>
        <span class="glyphicon check-mark hidden-glyph pull-right" width="30px">
        </span>
        <span class="text">Anime-Manga</span></a></li>
```

(Moving the first span after the second span doesnt do anything)
I have JQuery code that adds `glyphicon-ok` to the span and removes `hidden-glyph` when selected. It mostly works, but when you select the longest element in the list, the checkmark goes on top of the words.

Ideally the menu width would grow when it needed to, (ie only when the widest one is clicked), but I'm ok with it looking like:

`SOMETEXTGOESHERE |    |`
when its not selected and then the checkmark going into that spot when its done.

Ideas?

As requested:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lpprgmry/

Comment: Can you set up a [Fiddle?](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: You set up a Fiddle without Bootstrap included... Either add the required includes or use Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/

Comment: Ok I updated it a little, but can't publish my whole JS.